# Automatic Clicking on website drop down list

Tags: drop-down-menu, web

I am not sure if this can be done programmatically so I wanted to ask this question. There is this website that contains three drop down lists: the first selects a subject, the next selects the course number, and the third selects the section. If I supply all three categories and press submit, I get a list of books for the given course. I can add multiple courses and get books for multiple courses.

The problem I am having is that I want to get the books for all the courses and there are a lot of classes and a lot of sections to add. I am currently doing this manually and it is taking forever. Is there any way to auto fill the entire page with different combinations of these courses from the drop down list?

The reason for this is that once I hit submit, I am parsing the books result page using BeautifulSoup from Python. I unfortunately cannot find a database containing a list of all these books. So my only option would be to select the courses from the drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through some other technology and frameworks, I found out that Selenium can get the job done. Selenium has a webdriver that allows browser automation, and with it, you can simulate button clicks, drop down selection and much more. Selenium can work for many languages like Python and Java and mainly works on Firefox.